# AWS code doesn't exist when making a release build but it does for debug builds

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, pdftron

My app builds without problems when I'm doing a `debug` build but fails for a `release` build. I have to download the PDFTron libraries from AWS via the project build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "s3://pdftron-maven/release"
            credentials(AwsCredentials) {
                accessKey AWS_ACCESS_KEY
                secretKey AWS_SECRET_KEY
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I however get the error:

```
The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId; Request ID: 8733...; S3 Extended Request ID: zh7Nv...)
```

In my `gradle.properties` file I have declared

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY=...
AWS_SECRET_KEY=...
```

The build types I specified are:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

What's different about the `release` build from the `debug` build that could have caused this error?

Comment: Considering the available information, that should work. Please let us see the whole gradle and make sure your gradle.properties is not inside a debug directory. Another question, does AWS tie your key with a SHA? That cjange for debug and release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDFTron's Gradle integration has been changed, use the following instead:

```
maven {
    url "https://pdftron-maven.s3.amazonaws.com/release"
}
```

See: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/pdfnet-sdk/K9HMKRtrQmg for more details.